# openpyxl on Windows 10, Pycharm, consistently giving "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xxid'

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, openpyxl

I'm completely stuck. I'm a novice at Python, running Pycharm. I've tried various iterations of code involving openpyxl, coming to the conclusion that I've done something wrong and cannot for the life of me get openpyxl to run properly. I've installed the package openpyxl and with the below code, I always get an error. I'm on Windows 10 and have replicated this error across two of my devices.
Code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('MYDIRECTORY/FILENAME.xlsx')  # but I actually use proper path and name
sheet = workbook['PupilList']  # The name of my sheet
cell_value = sheet['A1'].value
print(cell_value)
```

Pretty basic, but even this throws up (as does all my other code involving this or pandas) the following error:

```
C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    workbook = load_workbook('C:/Users/ExamUser/Desktop/StudentDataCompiler/PupilList.xlsx')  # Replace 'your_file.xlsx' with the actual file path
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 299, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\ExamUser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xxid'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I'm extremely grateful for any help you can share.

I've tried different installs of python (3.9, the lastest, 3.8: all same result); I've tried fully uninstalling both python and pycharm, then reinstalling them. No joy.

Comment: I've not had any luck with openpyxl, nor pandas. I had the exact same error with pyexcel. It seems as though the file I'm trying to read, although .xlsx, is formatted in such a way that all these libraries hate it. I've had some luck with xlwings. I'll report back when I've finished my project.

Comment: So, the problem was totally about the formatting of the original .xlsx file. I cleaned the data first (manually) then copied-pasted the data into a new excel, saving it as .xlsx. This then runs with pandas. The files I've been using were supplied by our IT Team. I'll let them know.

Comment: Yes, opening the file in Excel and saving might be expected to fix the issue.

Comment: Ah, just saw this after I answered lol
Is it possible your IT team could be using other programs (open office I am looking at you) and then changing the file extension to xlsx manually?

Answer (score 1):

The OOXML Format on your file is likely incorrect - this is why openpyxl.load_workbook() is failing.

Here's some more info on it:
https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1931

One manual way you can fix the OOXML is to first open your file in excel, then save it.  Saving it should correct any OOXML problems.

Then you can rerun your script and it probably works fine.

Note that **this is intended behavior** for openpyxl - it rejects any files that don't conform to it's required file / data types.

One way in the future that you might be able to prevent stuff like this via script (if you had 100 excel files with this issue) might be, converting to CSV, then converting back to xlsx.

Comment: No need for a CSV. Just fix the styles.xml and save it back to the archive.